# How to account for variation in spelling (especially for slang) for Word Embeddings/Word2Vec generation using song lyrics?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, text-classification, spelling

So I am working on a artist classification project that utilizes hip hop lyrics from genius.com.  The problem is these lyrics are user generated, so the same word can be spelled in various different ways, especially if it is slang which is a very common case in hip hop.

I looked into spell correction using hunspell/pyhunspell, but the problem with that is it doesn't fix slang misspellings.  I technically could make a mini dictionary with a bunch of misspelled variations but that is effectively useless because there could be a dozen variations of the same word over my (growing) 6000 song corpus.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to stem your words. More information on stemming [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html). This would help grouping together words with close spelling variations.

A popular stemming scheme is the Porter Stemmer, which implementation can be found in most NLP packages, eg. [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/porter.html)

Comment: So from my under standing porter stemmer can be a bit too aggressive? Is this true?

Also, would lemmatizing work or no?

Comment: Lemmatizing would not work if the word is "misspelled" in the first place as it typically matches a dictionary. And there are various other stemmers, e.g. the [Snowball stemmer](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/snowball.html), that you can try. Note that the more "aggressive" it is, the more it will help you iron out those edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would discard, if possible, short words, or contracted words which somehow are too hard to automatically correct them (conditioned on checking that it won't affect your final result).

For longer words, you may want to use metrics like Levenshtein distance or Jaro similarity. The first one consists of the minimum number of additions, deletes or replaces to convert one candidate word into another. The second one, provides a similar result, between 0 and 1, and putting more emphasis in the last characters of a word.

If you have access to the correct version of your slang word, you could convert the closest candidates to the correct one. Of course, trying not to apply it to different correct words.

If you're working with Python, [here](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein) some implementations are provided.